# mod_rewrite : if / else type RewriteRule

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The following rewrite passes a string starting with the number 4 as a variable to process.php :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(4[^/]*)$ /process.php?variable=$1 [L]
```

So this

```
http://www.domain.com/4shopping
```

is mapped to

```
http://www.domain.com/process.php?variable=4shopping
```

But I want to extend this last rewrite rule to basically state:

```
if word begins with 4, map to /process.php?variable=$1
else map to /index.php
```

The second (else) part of this statement is the basic WordPress rewrite rule.  So for example:

```
http://www.domain.com/shopping
```

which has no 4 will be directed to

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?shopping (I believe this is how WordPress permalinks work!)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
RewriteRule ^(4[^/]*)$ /feedback.php?sms_code=$1 [L]
#
# BEGIN wordpress
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END wordpress
```

I left the default Wordpress rules in place, and added my own conditional rule above, making sure to terminate [L] processing if the condition was met

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(4[^/]*)$ process.php?variable=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^4/][^/]*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

The first rule will catch any request that can be mapped to an existing file or directory and will end the rewrite process. The second rule is yours (without the `RewriteCond` conditions). And the third rule will catch any request that’s URL path does not start with the number `4`.

Comment: For some reason the third rule doesn't work - i.e. normal WordPress URL's are resulting in a 'file not found' error.

Comment: Use mod_rewrite’s logging feature to see what’s going wrong. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel

Answer (score 0):

I would add two lines to the end of what you already have.  The additional rules will convert to index.php anything that hasn't already been converted to process.php.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(4[^/]*)$ /process.php?variable=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !process\.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?$1
```

Comment: Again, works in principle, but is not playing ball with Wordpress